# I have received 0.00000001 BTC random payment and the status symbol is a pentagram?

Tags: transactions, fraud

I have received 0.00000001 BTC random payment and the status symbol is a pentagram? Am I being used to tumble someone's stolen coin there are a lot of other wallets in the transaction?

Comment: A link to the tx on blockchain.info would be helpful.

Comment: Also, what wallet are you using?

Answer (score 3):

These were received from addresses starting with "1Enjoy" and "1Sochi", right? A lot of people got these today (including me). It is a part of some ongoing spamming effort of sorts - I wouldn't be too concerned with it.

Comment: Using Bitcoin transactions to propagate spam? Wow, now that's new. Could you please provide a reference on the blockchain??!!!

Comment: @JoePineda it's not new, but it's not effective.

Comment: I for one wouldn't be that much annoyed to receive that kind of spam vs. receiving via e-mail. After all, I'd be earning money, even if just tiny bits over time :)

Comment: @JoePineda Actually, you wouldn't earn anything. These transactions never actually validate - the two I got have been sitting there unconfirmed for five days now.